# Weird results when printing not existing list elements in C++

Tags: c++

So I am learning C++ at the moment and got some really weird results when I tried printing out element of a list of integers, that are actually out of range. (Don't ask why, I stumbled on that by accident)

---

This is my Code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int nums[0] = {};
    for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
        cout << nums[i] << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Results of when I ran the code the first time:

```
0
17110752
0
4199367
0
0
0
65
0
4225392
0
```

Results of when I ran the code a second time:

```
0
1906400
0
4199367
0
0
0
65
0
4225392
0
```

Results of when I ran the code a third time:

```
0
15603424
0
4199367
0
0
0
65
0
4225392
0
```

Every time I run this programm, the second number seems to be diffrent.

---

I know why I get unexpected results, but I'm curious where these values come from.

*Edit: "I know why I get unexpected results" is just poorly worded. What I meant was "I know that I get unexpected result, because I am calling a element that is not part of the list".*

Are they values from the RAM?
Why are some value repeating and some not?

Comment: The random value might be a canary to protect the stack. The values 4199367 (0x4013c7) and 4225392 (0x407970) looks like return addresses. You should look at the assembly code (disassembler output with addresses) and/or use GDB to inspect deeper.

Comment: It's whatever was in memory. That's it. I mean, if you were more curious, you could look into how a particular OS assigns a process its virtual memory.

Comment: try to see what happens when you turn on optimizations. Your code has undefined behavior. A compiler does not have to do anything meaningful with your code

Comment: *I know why I get unexpected results* -- Then I don't really understand your question.  You know the results are unexpected, but you're asking why the results are "weird".

Comment: Do you really want to dive into assembly language and the details of how C++ is implemented on your particular compiler / OS / etc? That's about the only way in which one could determine why any specific values are showing up.

Comment: As soon as there is UB (undefined behavior), it does not make much sense to try to understand it as the compiler can assumes that a program is free from undefined behavior and that might affect the generated code in ways that are hard to understand. In that particular case, the values you get probably depend on the code executed before `main` is called so you might need to debug startup code to understand the behavior which is really pointless.

Comment: @Phil1970 When I tried to inspect the stack in this manner (especially when I tried to index an array with a negative index) the programs would run as expected without optimization but completely skip the out-of-bounds access with optimization enabled. This happened both with VC and gcc.

Comment: As an aside, arrays with 0 elements are non-standard. The reason is probably that it is not exactly clear what it should be: Normally, an array is an immediate succession of objects of the element type in memory; the base address is the address of the first element. Now since there is no element, what is the base address? What does sizeof() yield? None of the invariants of regular arrays hold for zero-size arrays.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The result of compiling your code to (my invented) machine code is something like this.

```
1 main: 
2   reserve basePtr, 2       ; reserve 2 slots on the stack, and store in basePtr
3    mov    nums, basePtr     ;  num points at the first local variable
4    mov    [nums], 0         ; int num[1] = {0} - set num to zero
5    mov    i, basePtr + 1    ;  i points at second slot for local variables
6    mov    [i], 0            ; int i = 0;
7 for_loop:
8    cmp    [i], 10           ;
9    jmp_above_or_equal fini  ; exit loop
10   mov    tmp, [nums+i]     ;
11   call   cout, tmp
12   call   cout, std::endl   ;
13   inc    [i]
14   jmp    for_loop
15 fini:
16   return 0
```

So we reserve 2 slots for variables, and then read beyond the reserved space.

Imagine the call works like this :-

Initial stack

```
        +-----------+
        | ret_main  |   // crt code which calls main
        +-----------+
        |  nums[0]  |
        +-----------+
        |  i        |
SP->    +-----------+
```

push param (e.g. tmp) creates a stack like so...

```
        +-----------+
        | ret_main  |   // crt code which calls main
        +-----------+
        |  nums[0]  |
        +-----------+
        |  i        |
        +-----------+
        |  tmp      |
SP->    +-----------+
```

With the call itself....

```
        +-----------+
        | ret_main  |   // crt code which calls main
        +-----------+
        |  nums[0]  |
        +-----------+
        |  i        |
        +-----------+
        |  tmp      |
        +-----------+
        |  line_12  |
SP->    +-----------+
```

With this stack growing down through calls, your further requests are showing the memory values of the return address into your code, and the local variables of the previous call to cout.

If the stack grows the other way (more normal), a stack may look as so...

```
SP->    +-----------+
        | line_12   |   
        +-----------+
        |  tmp      |
        +-----------+
        |  i        |
        +-----------+
        |  nums[0]  |
        +-----------+
        |  ret_main |     // crt code which calls main
        +-----------+
```

This is the normal direction for stacks in modern processors.  In this case when you look further into the `nums` array, you are reading values of the return address for the function, and then the local variables which are from the function calling `main`.

In practice i is probably optimized into a register, and entry into a function would save some registry values based on the platform's calling conventions.

So the values you are reading, is likely to be in this order...

- Registers saved by main
- Values to detect against buffer overrun (which is happening here)
- Return address to main
- arguments to main
- local variables in the function which calls main.

Why are they repeating.  If the function calling main has copies of argv, then it would be likely the push to store argv are matched by the callers copy in local variables.
Why do some change.  Since Address Space Layout Randomization (ASLR), processes normally launch with a random base address, and random stack location, making it harder to exploit a buffer overflow.